# Is every large enough odd integer the sum of a prime or prime power and a power of $2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, goldbachs-conjecture

I've been thinking for some months about a slightly weaker form of Goldbach's conjecture: namely that every large enough integer is the sum of two prime powers or primes, that is $\exists C>0,\forall n>C,n=p^a+q^b$ with $p$ and $q$ primes and $a$ and $b$ positive integers. Of course if $n$ is odd, the truth of such a statement requires exactly one the two primes $p$ or $q$ to equal $2$.

I would like to know if the hypothetical exceptional set $E(x):=\#\{n\le x\mid n\equiv 1\pmod 2,\forall 0<k<\frac{\log n}{\log 2},\Lambda(n-2^k)=0\}$, where $\Lambda$ is the von Mangoldt function, is an $O(x^{1-\eta})$ for some $\eta>0$, conditionally or unconditionally.

Comment: See Cohen's article cited [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/153631/can-i-express-any-odd-number-with-a-power-of-two-minus-a-prime), at least for $p=2$ and $q^a=q$.

Comment: Thank you. The case of even integers remains open, I'll do my best to keep working on it.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Theorem 2 of that paper also covers the case of arbitrary prime power and a power of 2.

Comment: @Wojowu I see, very good. Thank you. I have read the paper now.